# Grab All CSS Used From A Webpage?

Tags: css, firefox

I am making a sub site, I would like a new CSS sheet thats cut down to just what that page needs.

What I would ideally like is a firefox extension that shows the CSS used on a currently viewed page, but not the CSS unused on that page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> What I would ideally like is a firefox
>   extension that shows the CSS used on a
>   currently viewed page, **but not the
>   CSS unused on that page**.

To see ***unused CSS***, you can use the [Dust Me Selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/) addon of firefox.

> It extracts all the selectors from all
>   the stylesheets on the page you're
>   viewing, then analyzes that page to
>   see which of those selectors are not
>   used. The data is then stored so that
>   when testing subsequent pages,
>   selectors can be crossed off the list
>   as they're encountered.
>
> You can test pages individually, or
>   spider an entire site, and you'll end
>   up with a profile of which selectors
>   are not used anywhere.

[image]

Comment: Thats kind of cool, but it doesnt let you save the actual CSS used

Comment: @azz0r If you are looking to for a way to remove the unused CSS, then your question should reflect that. It is a little unclear moment.

Comment: Im making a new style sheet that has just the things it needs, so essentially its a half full half empty kinda comparison.